# Metasploit search features returns intersection of results

Tags: exploit, metasploit

When I use multiple search criteria in Metasploit it shows the results as an "or" rather than an "and".  I see that this was asked several years ago so now I am wondering if this is a setting rather than the default.

```
msf6> search rce linux http
```

The results return the intersection of all those search terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use keywords for your search; otherwise, Metasploit searches for your terms in all fields.

Using your search as an example, it returns 255 hits (results truncated):

[image]

Then, using keywords:

```
msf6 > search  platform:linux  name:http description:"remote code execution"

Matching Modules
================

   #  Name                                         Disclosure Date  Rank       Check  Description
   -  ----                                         ---------------  ----       -----  -----------
   0  exploit/linux/misc/jenkins_ldap_deserialize  2016-11-16       excellent  Yes    Jenkins CLI HTTP Java Deserialization Vulnerability
   1  exploit/linux/http/ueb_api_rce               2017-08-08       excellent  Yes    Unitrends UEB http api remote code execution
```

You'll need to play with it a bit.  I had to use 'remote code execution' with the description keyword because 'rce' didn't return any hits.  The Jenkins exploit is in the results because its name in the database has 'http' in it:

```
msf6 > info 0

       Name: Jenkins CLI HTTP Java Deserialization Vulnerability
```

Use 'help search' from the Metasploit command line to see the keywords and some other commands:

```
Usage: search [<options>] [<keywords>:<value>]

Prepending a value with '-' will exclude any matching results.
If no options or keywords are provided, cached results are displayed.


OPTIONS:

    -h, --help                      Help banner
    -I, --ignore                    Ignore the command if the only match has the same name as the search
    -o, --output <filename>         Send output to a file in csv format
    -r, --sort-descending <column>  Reverse the order of search results to descending order
    -S, --filter <filter>           Regex pattern used to filter search results
    -s, --sort-ascending <column>   Sort search results by the specified column in ascending order
    -u, --use                       Use module if there is one result

Keywords:
  adapter          :  Modules with a matching adater reference name
  aka              :  Modules with a matching AKA (also-known-as) name
  author           :  Modules written by this author
  arch             :  Modules affecting this architecture
  bid              :  Modules with a matching Bugtraq ID
  cve              :  Modules with a matching CVE ID
  edb              :  Modules with a matching Exploit-DB ID
  check            :  Modules that support the 'check' method
  date             :  Modules with a matching disclosure date
  description      :  Modules with a matching description
  fullname         :  Modules with a matching full name
  mod_time         :  Modules with a matching modification date
  name             :  Modules with a matching descriptive name
  path             :  Modules with a matching path
  platform         :  Modules affecting this platform
  port             :  Modules with a matching port
  rank             :  Modules with a matching rank (Can be descriptive (ex: 'good') or numeric with comparison operators (ex: 'gte400'))
  ref              :  Modules with a matching ref
  reference        :  Modules with a matching reference
  stage            :  Modules with a matching stage reference name
  stager           :  Modules with a matching stager reference name
  target           :  Modules affecting this target
  type             :  Modules of a specific type (exploit, payload, auxiliary, encoder, evasion, post, or nop)
  action           :  Modules with a matching action name or description

Supported search columns:
  rank             :  Sort modules by their exploitability rank
  date             :  Sort modules by their disclosure date. Alias for disclosure_date
  disclosure_date  :  Sort modules by their disclosure date
  name             :  Sort modules by their name
  type             :  Sort modules by their type
  check            :  Sort modules by whether or not they have a check method
  action           :  Sort modules by whether or not they have actions

Examples:
  search cve:2009 type:exploit
  search cve:2009 type:exploit platform:-linux
  search cve:2009 -s name
  search type:exploit -s type -r
```

Comment: I appreciate the lengthy explanation. Using the specific call outs for platform and description did the trick.